# Is there a Spring function that will remove a quote character or delimiter in a CSV file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csv, spring-batch

I am reading a million record file in `Spring` where fields are quoted with the `"` character and the delimiter is a `|` character.

Example:

> "name1"|"name2"|"na"me3"|"name4"|....

I use:

```
DelimitedLineTokenizer.setQuoteCharacter('"')
```

to remove the double quote characters, but the double quote within the `name3` field is not handled correctly.

Issue - the results are:

```
Obj.name1 = name1 
Obj.name2= name2
Obj.name3 = name3|name4 
Obj.name4 = null
```

Comment: Hey, can You please try to add more information. A code example + input and output and expected output. Please also try to use code formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [CSV RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), section 2.7, your CSV file is not valid. Here is an excerpt from the specification:

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote

If you escape the `"` as mentioned in the RFC, Spring Batch will correctly tokenize the line, here is a quick (passing) test with v4.2.2:

```
@Test
public void testSo61636078() {
    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setDelimiter("|");
    tokenizer.setQuoteCharacter('"');
    FieldSet fieldSet = tokenizer.tokenize("\"name1\"|\"name2\"|\"na\"\"me3\"|\"name4\"");
    assertEquals(4, fieldSet.getFieldCount());
    assertEquals("name1", fieldSet.readString(0));
    assertEquals("name2", fieldSet.readString(1));
    assertEquals("na\"me3", fieldSet.readString(2));
    assertEquals("name4", fieldSet.readString(3));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet ! Mahmoud.  Finally i can enclose the issue !!